# Extracting elements from html using VBA

Tags: html, vba, msxml

I need to extract posts from a forum webpage using VBA. From code snippets on the web I have got as far as successfully extracting the text for each post. But I can't get at the poster's name. The code I'm using is:

```
Sub extract_forum_posts()
Dim htm As Object: Set htm = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://community.betfair.com/your_competitions/go/thread/view/94214/30587277/division-1-thursday-17-september?sdb=1&pg=last#546245865", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    End With

    For Each div In htm.getElementsByTagName("div")

        If div.classname Like "*flvPostContent*" Then
            Debug.Print div.innertext
        End If
    Next div
End Sub
```

The poster's name seems to be part of a span element. Don't know what that is.

Comment: Please don't use VBA for this, you can use virtually any other language on the planet (php, python, ruby, javascript, go) just not VBA - you will got mad.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using this in excel and don't have an alternative.  And I'm too old to start learning completely new languages that I'm unlikely to use much!

Answer (score 2):

Each posted message seems to be encompassed in a div element with a .classname starting with `flvPost flvPost`. There are div children in that posting div element that comprise different aspects of the post. The username information is nested into anchor and  span elements within a child div with a classname of `flvPostInfo`.

```
For Each div In htm.getelementsbytagname("div")
    If div.classname Like "flvPost flvPost*" Then
        For d = 0 To div.getelementsbytagname("div").Length - 1
            Select Case div.getelementsbytagname("div")(d).classname
                Case "flvPostInfo"
                    Debug.Print "user: " & div.getelementsbytagname("div")(d).innertext
                Case "flvPostContent"
                    Debug.Print "mssg: " & div.getelementsbytagname("div")(d).innertext
            End Select
        Next d
        'Exit For  'shorten the scrape for testing purposes
    End If
Next div
```

Comment: @John Fowler - If you are looking to learn by example, try taking on a few of the questions posed in the [tag:xmlhttp] and [tag:xmlhttprequest] forums. Ignore the ones that don't provide a public URL to actually test your solutions.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped that seems to get me most of the way there. I was trying to extract the "title" part in:

Comment: /a>
<span class="flvPostInfoName">
<a href="http://community.betfair.com/dogdayafternoon"
class="flvPostInfoNameLink"
id="flvPostInfoNameLink-546240333"
title="dogdayafternoon"
data-user_id="77413318"
>dogdayafternoon</a>
</span>

Comment: I know I can extract the string I want from the flvPostContent but a more elegant solution would be to get the title bit.

Comment: The structure of that page seems fairly predictable albeit a little messy. There are functions to get the parent, siblings or children that will work you up, down or sideways through the HTML hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector:**

You can use a CSS selector  of `a[id^='flvPostInfoNameLink']`

This says `a` tag elements with `id` attribute that starts with `'flvPostInfoNameLink'`

---

**CSS query (Sample matches):**

[image: Sample matches]

---

**VBA:**

Use the `querySelectorAll` method of document to return a `nodeList` of all matching elements. You then loop the `.Length` to retrieve elements.

```
Dim aNodeList As Object, iNode As Long
Set aNodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll("a[id^='flvPostInfoNameLink']")
For iNode = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print aNodeList.item(iNode).innerText
    'Debug.Print aNodeList(iNode).innerText '<== Sometimes this syntax
Next iNode
```